# How do I infer to TypeScript that a property can only be of one type based on filtered keys?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to find a way to build a function that takes in a state, only allows specifying a property name based on a type (in this case `string`) and then doing something with that property.

In the following case everything works well except within the body of the function. The line `return prop.substr(0) + payload` errors because TypeScript cannot infer by this point that `state[property]` could only ever refer to a property that is of type string.

```js
type StringKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never }[keyof T]

const state = { one: 'string', two: 34, three: true }

type StateStringKeys = StringKeys<typeof state> // ✓ should only contain 'one'

const combineStrings = <S, P extends StringKeys<S>>(state: S, property: P, payload: S[P]): string => {
  const prop = state[property]
  return prop.substr(0) + payload // X - How do I tell TS that this could only ever be a string by now?
}
combineStrings(state, 'one', 'test') // ✓ should NOT error, 'one' is a string and a string is provided
combineStrings(state, 'one', 23) // ✓ should error, 'one' is a string but a number is provided
combineStrings(state, 'two', 23) // ✓ should error, 'two' is a number
combineStrings(state, 'three', 'test') // ✓ should error, 'three' is a boolean
combineStrings(state, 'four', false) // ✓ should error, 'four' does not exist
```

Is there any way in this to have the same type safety when calling the function but also infer the correct type of `string` for `prop`.

Here's a [link on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=78&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwNIRAZwDwBUA+KAXigG8oBtdKFKAaywHsAzKfAXQC4ObOoEAB7AIyACbYo2BClRQA-FFq9kEAG4R4UAL5UmINh04BYAFDmAxs2QzpwAIajSFKDYi8A5DKRpPAGihgAHdmXgBmABZA4AALeAgPIPgAV2gdc3NQSFhHUThfDCwpMgK5TBxcbIgjGScIYgB6RqhAZHJpWOYUgBtxN2RukChrZEd6T3dPTLMRu2sAWwAjFAgytBKoXBhAgAVBETFJXMKKvBhCQgAKOtFebagweGZIeFBeHcCwBxBu5gdxO5UHacACUvB8clIxHI5igwxsdkezxcNwgVCRL1ApjMcISwBS8GQDyeYAAdNgUosfJcAAwgqAAage31+-ygzSgAA0oABaKAACWYwSg4mYUAAkkEIN1uhwYEFYk4FYgpNYen0bINBJptItoA57IUoIshsghQpzBkZswlis1qhsNc8hBAhM1AEoJ5RDJPPSOe1sJ11VAAHIAeXwgngT3grsmdCkBohaCgDgkqcNkJVxOY6kQ4gg4isNuWantjtRcfdgQATOE-S0A0HelGY1WIJ4Exnk-JFilgBnkCkllou0i8wWi9bbWXZOsnfVXSFmB66w22h0ui2tG3PcvO9mDUOR-BizPVnOHQvREv4okPV6ID7102t30d8xY3u7x2uwbFswzDdBAaZnqWF6FBWzquqwXTwB6rAON02AQC+m7Bh+X6eLBBKdqKT5QGaA7CCqwDmEAA) if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is to revert the constrain at the type level, force object to extend object with string values. Consider:

```
const combineStrings =
  < S extends Record<P, string> // here we say that object has P property as string
  , P extends keyof S >(state: S, property: P, payload: S[P]): string => {
  const prop = state[property]
  return prop.substr(0) + payload // works 
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=2&pln=3&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBNCGUCmMC8MDeNxIFwwHJoAnASzAHMCAaGKAdxHwGYAWWqAC2KTzuICuKAL4BYAFATQkWKAC2AI3JIAylDKUIaCTBgAeGCphIAHsjAATLQCUkoYhb0AFWiXIUAfDAD03mJyQeGHoUCHgATzpORGwFACs7WGitJxgAB2IQNMCoSPgtN0odGFpU03MrGABrJHCQADNDGA8ACgRkfBVaDKyc8PwXdIiAGxB4C06AbScAXQBKfEKKNC8MYulodMy0tDgoRCRJnuziXJninigBYjAtrIA6CAEFEhaABjmYAGoh8NHxnx%20RjEKpaQC8G4BZHYkYnE8iUYFU6ncEDa%202QtAIOBohGQ0AIn18MEAyORwTggATDCwwAByAHkACrGYiZYgYrEwUhaeB7DTLeCWGDcpYcrQ9ABupAsSAsUhAimUal5KPaSDZCOxACZmAS-CSIGSKVTAiy1UgCCLBTz3DAFAJYNywAJFIELeLJdLZfKEYrkaiDhiGCBNdrAcTSeTKUyTTjGObOZbHc7iJ74YilX70TjuLxsQRcVB8aG9QbI8aQKyszwzRbuQoQCBhkh%20SmFUjNBnVYR6uTiNj6vBhhAkDqw-qI0bmeWMd3ruaLCAkFowCBYKZOVAgA)

Comment: This is much simpler than I thought, thanks. As a bonus you can also constrain `P` to only the string keys which makes intellisense a lot nicer as it only provides you with keys that are strings (`P extends keyof S & StringKeys<S>`)